# GLib 2.22 to run Thunderbird

Tags: release-freya, applications

I am running 64bit elementary OS 0.3 Freya and I would like to use Thunderbird as an email client for my Gmail account. I have downloaded it from [the website](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) as the Software Centre has Thunderbird 31 and Gmail requires Thunderbird 38 or newer.

However when I try to run Thunderbird I get:

```
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/gthomson/thunderbird/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

I [know](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/31.0/system-requirements/) that Thunderbird requires GLib 2.22 or higher to run but I don't know what package I should download to fix this issue.?

Comment: Have you tried any of the recommendations here http://askubuntu.com/questions/648463/cant-install-thunderbird-38-1-on-ubuntu-14-04 ?

Comment: Since today Thunderbird 38.2 is available via official repositories. Take a look at my [answer](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1594/22)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using the official [Thunderbird PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next) instead.

- Add `ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next` to your sources,
- Update the software sources,
- Then upgrade Thunderbird.

Commandline option:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird 38.2 is now available in the official repositories. I strongly recommend to use the official stable release instead of an unstable beta repository.
In case you have been following [RolandiXor's answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1390/22), you need to remove the `ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next` repository, update your sources, and reinstall Thunderbird:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall thunderbird
```

If you didn't install any beta version, just install Thunderbird:

```
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, to  search the repositories for a package you are looking for you can use apt-cache search. In your case:

```
apt-cache search libdbus-glib
```

There you will get a list of packages that have a match. Packages ending in "-dev" or "-dbg" are more oriented for developers or those compiling applications. "-doc" are document oriented packages. I believe in your case you want the `libdbus-glib-1-2` package.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2
```

Comment: Thanks zlalanne but I already have libdbus-glib-1-2 installed.